# Passing value of variable from one method to another in a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need the value of `@begin_date` and `@end_date` from index action in the `update_log` as I need those value for querying.

I used class variable for it, BUT it only works the first time, as you can see from code below for `Date.parse(params[:begin_date])` there is a form tag I have written in the index view.

```
class TController < ApplicationController

@@begin_date = Date.today

@@end_date = Date.today

def index

  @begin_date = params[:begin_date].present? ? Date.parse(params[:begin_date]) : Date.today.beginning_of_month

  @end_date = params[:end_date].present? ? Date.parse(params[:end_date]) : Date.today.end_of_month

  @@begin_date = @begin_date 
  @@end_date = @end_date 
end

def update_log
  @begin_date2 = @@begin_date
  @end_date2 = @@end_date
end
```

In `update_log` action it's only taking the value of:

```
@@begin_date = Date.today

@@end_date = Date.today
```

But after the value is changed from form tag for date it is not getting updated in `update_log`. I need help with this, OR someone can suggest me a better way of getting the result.

Comment: `before_filter` or `before_action` depending on your rails version [Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Answer (score 0):

Assign them the same way that in your index action :

```
def update_log
  @begin_date = the_value
  @end_date   = the_value
end
```